# Adjust Background noice sensitivity in Android Speech-to-text recognition

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, sfspeechrecognizer, android-speech-api

Android Speech-to-text is very sensitive to background noises. The use-case is to use Speech-to-text in an area where light background noises will be constant. Want to control the speech recognition only with certain voice levels.

Tried working around using **RMS and Buffer input from Speech Recogniser**. Some workaround using same logic would be helpful.

Callbacks returned from Android Speech-to-text recogniser are :

```
override fun onReadyForSpeech(params: Bundle?) {
    }
override fun onRmsChanged(rmsdB: Float) {
    }
override fun onBufferReceived(buffer: ByteArray?) {
    }
override fun onEvent(eventType: Int, params: Bundle?) {
    }
override fun onBeginningOfSpeech() {
    }
override fun onEndOfSpeech() {
    }
override fun onError(error: Int) {
    }
override fun onPartialResults(partialResults: Bundle?){
    }
override fun onResults(results: Bundle?) {
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean that the recognition quality is not acceptable or something else?